# can anyone assess my g parted screen capture

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

Can anyone explain to me what happened ?

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 and thought I was replacing Windows. I have a backup but I'm afraid to plug it in.

I hope my `D:` drive with my data is untouched... but I don't know.

Note: I'll try to attach two screen captures. One of the gparted data and another with a capture of my "computer".

I am interested in the `initrd.img` file.

[image: gparted]

Comment: ok I cannot seem to post a image

Comment: You'll need 10 reputation to upload an image. You could upload it elsewhere and leave a link in your question, it'll help us answer you.

Comment: how does one get a higher rep.  I am trying chat rooms but the same there

Comment: I edited your answer with the first IMG you tried to upload, you have to accept my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you overwrote everything on your drive. Did you have a separate partition on your main hard drive that was mounted in Windows as drive `D:`? If so it would appear that it is gone.

If you have that partition backed up, this will help you restore your files.

Boot into your Ubuntu install CD and repartition your drive to include a data partition that you can mount in Ubuntu.

Format the partition to either ext3 or ext4 and make it as large as you like.

Reboot so you boot from your internal hard drive and plug in your drive with the backup and copy all the files to the new partition you just created.

I'm not sure what you want to know about the `initrd.img` file, but reading the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) might put your mind at ease. I don't think its your problem.

Your system is just two partitions. One large partition that is your Ubuntu OS, and a small boot partition needed to boot Ubuntu. If you didn't back up your data you are out of luck. If its backed up just restore it by following the instructions above, or a myriad of others on the web.

Comment: This is helpful however I would like to address the screen capture of devices/computer....in that window there are folders and 4 files    initrd.img     initrd.img.old     vmlinuz      and vmlinuz.old    I am wondering if  these are related to the partition image  since it says that lvm2 pv is 148.81 gb size wizw and that the same amount is "used"   Did the install mirror my hard drive and put it there.  I ask this because it appears to be zipped

Comment: I dont know how to "pharagraph".  Every time I try (hit enter) it posts